# Google apps script deployment permissions required separately for spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

When running the app Getting: You do not permission to access requested document line 66. (offending line is attempting to open a spreadsheet:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
```

Do I need to set permissions separately for **both** the spreadsheet and the application?

I deployed code as a web app, with permissions set to 'anyone'. I selected: Who has access to the app: to 'Anyone', and
Execute the app as: 'User accessing the web app'

I want to share the app with colleagues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You need to set permissions separately for both the spreadsheet and the application if you set the web app to run as *User accessing the web app*. This is not needed if you set the webapp to run as *Me*.

Answer (score 0):

The web app published from Google Apps Script has it's own access settings no matter if the script is a bounded or a standalone script. Using "User access the we app" on a web app that use SpreadsheetApp methods to access an spreadshet implies that the spreadsheet should be share with those users.